# VS2015 adding dependency to project.json doesn't show Autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am following along to a video and the user types in 'static' in the project dependencies section and gets Autocomplete for "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final" in the project.json file dependencies section but as I am typing along I don't get any Autocomplete. Its the same issue when I try to add "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"...I don't get the Autocomplete, so I don't even know what version to manually type in. Is this user error?

```
      "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "static"
  },
```

expected Autocomplete to provide this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

This is what I get with the AutoComplete right now for EntityFramework:

[image]

Update:
I am following along code from a Lynda.com Up and running with ASP.Net 5 video series, and the lesson video shows this as autocomplete:

[image]

But when I follow along, I don't get the same:

[image]

Comment: What is your full Visual Studio version? Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: uhm yes. its VS2015 Pro with Update 2.

Comment: When you type a ", do you get intellisense? If you open NuGet Manager can you search and browse NuGet packages from nuget.org feed (just determining of your feeds are still in order)?

Comment: Updated the original post to show some color on what I see when I follow along to a Lynda.com video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to make sure package sources are enabled/checked in Visual Studio under Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources.

My Machine-wide Packages/Microsoft and .NET was not checked (which is kinda strange because I did do a default install) but checking that solved my issue.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that is why I asked this question: "If you open NuGet Manager can you search and browse NuGet packages from nuget.org feed (just determining of your feeds are still in order)?" Glad you found it out. Always tricky, those feeds.